# How to fix: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am attempting to create a madlibs for a small hw assignment. Trying to fix this error in line 15.

I've tried using "str(None)" instead of just the plan "' '"

```
import random

print('Time for M A D L I B S')
print('Enter examples of some zany words for each category!! Use quote marks')

random_name = input("Enter random name:")
your_name = input('Enter your own name:')
place = input('Enter a place:')
adjective = input('Enter an adjective:')

adjs = ['crazy', 'nice', 'awesome', 'big','tiny']
verbs = ['met', 'ran', 'farted', 'sat on', 'hugged']
prepositions = ['above the', 'near the', 'around the', 'behind', 'beside']

print(random.choice(adjs)) + ' ' + random_name + ' ' + print(random.choice(verbs)) + ' ' + your_name + ' ' + print(random.chioce(prepositions)) + ' ' + adjective + ' ' + place


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "madlibs.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(random.choice(adjs)) + ' ' + random_name + ' ' + print(random.choice(verbs)) + ' ' + your_name + ' ' + print(random.chioce(prepositions)) + ' ' + adjective + ' ' + place
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 15:

```
print(random.choice(adjs)) + ' ' + random_name + ' ' + print(random.choice(verbs)) + ' ' + your_name + ' ' + print(random.chioce(prepositions)) + ' ' + adjective + ' ' + place
```

You're concatenating `print(random.choice(verbs))`, which returns a `NoneType`, with `str` types. Try removing the extra print statements so it looks like:

```
print(random.choice(adjs)) + ' ' + random_name + ' ' + random.choice(verbs) + ' ' + your_name + ' ' + random.chioce(prepositions) + ' ' + adjective + ' ' + place)
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course it was something so simple. Appreciate it!